# Get checksum without built in Get-FileHash cmdlet in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, md5, powershell-3.0, checksum

I cannot use the built in cmdlet `Get-FileHash` to generate checksum value as the version of Powershell is lower than 4.

Is there an alternative way of getting or validating the integrity of the file?

Answer (score 4):

OK lets assume you have a file item (from Get-ChildItem for example)

```
$stream = new-object system.IO.FileStream($item.fullname, "Open", "Read", "ReadWrite")
```

You open the file with FileStream to get a stream object.

Then you can use one of the Crypto classes to compute its hash:

```
if ($stream)
{
      $sha = new-object -type System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed
      $bytes = $sha.ComputeHash($stream)
      $stream.Dispose()
      $stream.Close()
      $sha.Dispose()
      $checksum = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($bytes).Replace("-", [String]::Empty).ToLower();
}
```

Finally the checksum is in `$checksum` and it's a nice string you can use for your compare:

```
5989b3cdcff6a594b2b2aef7f6288f7727019c037515c2b10627721e707cf613
```

You have all sort of classes to compute hashes under `System.Security.Cryptography`, you can see what is available here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You should `Dispose()` the `$sha` instance as well

Comment: Hey could you chime in here? It's related to using this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71611732/why-cant-these-files-be-accessed-by-the-system-via-stream-new-object-system?noredirect=1#comment126564451_71611732

Comment: Never mind, realized it was more of an access problem with some system files needing permission changes.